# trouble finding query to display names having ratings greater than a given value

Tags: mysql

table apartment >

```
apartment_id || apartment_name || status
==============================
 1                         joys                active
 5                         harrys              active  
 10                        tols                active
```

table ratings >

```
user_id || apartment_id || rating
===================================
  1              1                  4
  2              5                  3
  3              10                 4
  4              10                 5
```

i need to get the apartment names which has  ratings greater than a value(say 'x')..if the same apartment has more than 1 ratings from different users(like in apartment_id = 10) the apartment should be returned if the average is greater than the 'x'..

```
SELECT a.*  FROM  `apartment` AS a     LEFT JOIN `ratings` AS b ON a.`apartment_id` = b.`apartment_id` WHERE  a.`status` NOT IN ('inactive')  AND (b.apartment_id IN (SELECT apartment_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `rating` > x)) GROUP BY a.`apartment_id`
```

the above query works fine if the apartment has only one rating..pls help in case where apartment has more than one rating value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.apartment_name,
       t.avg_rating
FROM apartment a
LEFT JOIN(SELECT s.apartment_id , AVG(s.rating) as avg_rating
     FROM ratings s
     GROUP BY s.apartment_id
     HAVING AVG(s.rating) > <X..> ) t
 ON(t.apartment_id = a.apartment_id)
WHERE a.status NOT IN ('inactive')
```

Comment: there seems to be some problem with the query...all the apartments in the **apartment** table  with "status=active" is being diplayed irrespective of the ratings..apartments which are in **apartments**  table but not present in **ratings**  table are also being displayed

Comment: @ashwin Those are your filters, not mine. If you want only results that appear in both tables, use `INNER JOIN` and not `LEFT JOIN` . If you want only not active that use ` NOT IN('active')` and not `NOT IN('inactive')`

Comment: changed LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN..working successfully..thanku @sagi